# re-Loading a swf the second time is 2 seconds slower

Tags: apache-flex

The first time I load my SWF when I start my browser, it takes 5 seconds.
Then, when I reload in my browser it takes 7 seconds (and all subsequent loads) take 7 seconds.

When I restart my browser it takes 5 seconds again.  (and reloads take 7 seconds).

It is very consistently reproduceable.

Any ideas on what this might be?  Is this common?

Comment: User a network sniffer to find out what is going on.  Is your problem "load time"; that is time it takes for the SWF to be sent to the browser? Or is the problem app "setup" time; which is the time it takes for the app to be usable?  It seems highly unlikely you'd be able to test this in an environment that gives consistent results; as many factors such as network latency, will be a moving target.

Comment: My problem is the "setup time".  I attached Adobe Scout and I can see that in the first case for all frames I spend about 21 ms "Waiting for Next frame".  In the next case it spends 500-700 ms "Waiting for next frame" on *every* frame.  When I say I am geting consistent results I mean += 100 ms.  I'm running using a local tomcat so network latency isn't really an issue anyways.  Certain not able to account for the 2 second difference.  How can I figure out/Stop flex from "Waiting for next Frame"?  (I've tried changing the framerate already, it doesn't seem to help..)

Comment: Flex has a lot of "Framework" setup to do before the app is useable.  I think the preloader is shown during this time.  It is confusing that you consistently see 5 seconds on the first load and 7 seconds on subsequent loads.  Without reviewing code I'm not sure if we'll be able to help.

Comment: I was able to figure it out. The div component I was trying to embedd my flash into was not visible and thus (I guess) Flash decides to give it a lower rendering priority.  Once I made the div visible, all is well.

Comment: That is good information to know. I have heard that flash will throttle non-active SWFs in order to not cause performance problems on the machine.  You should post your solution as a formal answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question from the comments above:

I was able to figure it out. The div component I was trying to embedd my flash into was not visible and thus (I guess) Flash decides to give it a lower rendering priority. Once I made the div visible, all is well.